# How to send automatic mails from QTP (not summary !!)

Tags: email, automation, qtp

So I know how to send automatic **summary mails** from QTP.

But this is not the kind of informations I need, in fact I want the LongComments of my tests.

The thing is the content of "**test result**" mails are exactly what I need, so this is perfect but how to send it **automatically** at the end of my tests ?

I mean the point of using QTP is automation and I'm not able to automate one of the functionnality of the soft, I'm quite perplexed here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will work if you have an outlook agent installed and logged in on your test machine. You might have to write case statements based on your test results.
You can also access the mail server directly that way you don't have to install/login an outlook agent.

```
Function sendemail 

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set sndmail= objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

'Set properties
sndmail.To = "abc@gmail.com"
sndmail.CC = "abc@gmail.com; def@yahoo.com" 
sndmail.Subject = "Sending mail"
sndmail.Body= "Test Contents"
sndmail.Attachments.Add("C:\Test.txt") 'Path of the file  
'Send the mail
sndmail.Send


'Clear object 
Set sndmail= Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function fnSendEmailFromOutlook

'Create an object of type Outlook
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

'Set the email properties
myMail.To = "some_mail_id@gmail.com"
myMail.CC = "some_mail_id_2@gmail.com; some_other_mail@yahoo.com" 'Sending mails to multiple ids
myMail.BCC = "" 'If BCC is not required, then this line can be omitted
myMail.Subject = "Sending mail from MS Outlook using QTP"
myMail.Body= "Test Mail Contents"
myMail.Attachments.Add("D:\Attachment.txt") 'Path of the file to be attached

'Send the mail
myMail.Send
Wait(3)

'Clear object reference
Set myMail = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Seriously, this is almost identical to the answer that was already provided.